# Putting "foot in mouth" or "foot in it"?

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

I know the expression *putting foot in ones mouth* and I'm **not** asking about its meaning. However, as I was verifying that I got the idiom perfectly correct, I stumbled upon the following [example sentence](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+foot+in+mouth) and I'm surprised by it.

> I put my foot in it by telling John's secret; he found out.

Is it also a proper way to use the idiom or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! Both phrases mean the same thing.

See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_one's_foot_in_it):

> To make a mistake in public, or a social blunder, that is embarrassing, or offensive.

And [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+foot+in+it):

> put your foot in it  (British, American & Australian informal) also put your foot in your mouth (American)
>   to say something by accident which embarrasses or upsets someone
>   *I really put my foot in it with Julie. I didn't realise she was a vegetarian.*

As a corollary, this is also referred to as "[Foot in mouth disease](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/foot-in-mouth+disease)". Someone with *foot in mouth disease* has a tendency to put their foot in their mouth on a regular basis

---

* <sup>Not to be confused with "[foot **and** mouth disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-and-mouth_disease)", an infectious disease affecting hooved animals.</sup>

Comment: Actually, it might be the case that the expression **is indeed** related to the disease, after all. At least of you trust [some peoples' theories](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-origin-of-the-expression-put-ones-foot-in-ones-mouth). Also, +1 for links and sources.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Oh, it's certainly referential to it... but it's not **actually** the illness.. which I don't believe humans are susceptible to.